# Usage of React Redux in Modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning Redux in React. I am using Redux in React for Modal development. My code is like below

```
render() {
    return (
      <Modal id="addressModal" open={this.props.controlModal} onClose={this.props.action}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          {this.props.addresObj ? (
            <Modal.Header>Address Details</Modal.Header>
          ) : (
            <Modal.Header>Insert Address</Modal.Header>
          )}
          <Modal.Content>
              <ModalElement
                update={this.update}
                element={this.props.addresObj}
                errors = {this.state.errors}
                update_state_photo={this.update_state_photo}
                address={this.props.address}
                action={this.props.action}
              />
          </Modal.Content>

          <Modal.Actions>
            {this.props.addresObj ? (
              <Button
                positive
                icon="checkmark"
                labelPosition="right"
                onClick={this.closeModal}
                content="OK"
              />
            ) : (
              <Button
                positive
                icon="checkmark"
                labelPosition="right"
                onClick={this.insertAddress}
                content="Save"
              />
            )}
          </Modal.Actions>
        </Provider>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

(Did I use `<Provider store={store}>` properly ?) In child component I can't use Redux syntax. Like if I use this `export default connect()(EditableRow);` I am getting error (component execution is not finish at that component, execution forwared). If I use this syntax `export default EditableRow;` I am not getting any error.

May be I could not express my issue properly.

Here is my repo    https://github.com/afoysal/mern/blob/master/client/src/components/ModalBody.js

I am getting below error.

[image]

How to use Redux in React Modal ?

Comment: Where do you import `Modal` ? You created that component or is a third party library?

Comment: Thanks @Vencovsky. I created component.

Comment: want to put everything wrap inside `<Provider store={}>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here arise from using [React portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

Portal allows to render React elements under another DOM none. With simplifications this will look like

```
const ComponentA = ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <CoolComponent />,
    document.getElementById('banner'),
)

const ComponentB = ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <SuperCoolComponent />,
    document.getElementById('footer'),
)
```

So in gneral `ComponentA` will not see `Provider` of `ComponentB`.

You may look at this [page](https://dev.to/mickmister/sharing-context-with-react-portals-4dki), however it does not fully describe problem you faced.

If look to `<Modal>` component source, it uses [`React.createPortal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render itself and looses parent's provider.

One workaround I see

1. Extract `store` from partner's `<Provider/>`
2. Create new `<Provider>` just after `<Modal>` usage.

   ```
   // ModelBody.js
   import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';

   //...
   render() {
       return (
           <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
               {((ctx) => (
                   <Modal id="addressModal" open={this.props.controlModal} onClose={this.props.action}>
                       <Provider store={ctx.store}>  /* make store available in Portal */
                           {this.props.addresObj ? (
                               <Modal.Header>Address Details</Modal.Header>
                           ) : (
                               <Modal.Header>Insert Address</Modal.Header>
                           )}
                       /* other code from Model.js */
                       </Provider>
                   </Modal>
              )).bind(this) // Dont forget to bind this
          }
      </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Fyodor for your reply. Here is the repo  https://github.com/afoysal/mern/blob/master/client/src/components/ModalBody.js  . You can check.

Comment: How do you run this app? I've cloned your repo on Windows pc but cannot start it. I've reinstalled npm modules, but still have no luck

Comment: Thanks @Fyodor. I am using linux mint 19. I run project with `npm run dev` command like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLAtv.png. I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Many Many Thanks @Fyodor. You are really genius.  Your solution is working. Thanks and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you didn't wrap everything inside  properly,
once wrapped, its accessible throughout the app,
as redux states there must be single source of truth,
do try to follow principles.

```
// ModelBody.js
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';

//...
render() {
    return (

        <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
            {((ctx) => (
         <Provider store={ctx.store}>
                <Modal id="addressModal" open={this.props.controlModal} onClose={this.props.action}>
                      /* make store available in Portal */
                        {this.props.addresObj ? (
                            <Modal.Header>Address Details</Modal.Header>
                        ) : (
                            <Modal.Header>Insert Address</Modal.Header>
                        )}
                    /* other code from Model.js */

                </Modal>
           </Provider>
           )).bind(this) // Dont forget to bind this
       }
   </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
```

or try to wrap your whole app, `index.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Kamble. Your fist solution is not working. Second solution is not matching with my component. Did you check the repo of github ?  https://github.com/afoysal/mern/blob/master/client/src/index.js