# Can't connect redux store to sematic ui dimmer components

Tags: reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

I am using React with semantic-ui-react library. The problem is when i use semantic-ui Dimmer and try to connect a component inside it to redux i get the error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(myComp)"`.
I managed to get over this error by wrapping the inner component in Provider like this:

```
import { Dimmer } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../storelocation/store'
import SubComp from './subComp'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Dimmer>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <SubComp/>
                    </Provider>
                </Dimmer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Doing this, my SubComp is now able to `connect(mstp,mdtp)`.

Such problem is not showing up in any other part of the app. I have wrapped my root component in Provider in my `index.js` like this:

```
ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now since wrapping my SubComp in provider each time i use it, fades the smile from my face, i am looking for a better option and maybe a correction if i am doing something terribly wrong here. tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here occurs because Semantic-UI-React uses [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for components like Modal, Confirm, Dimmer, Popup etc.

For more information about Portals and why this problem occurs, you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56266982/6022448) comment.

Unfortunately there seems to be no better way than wrapping your own components under Portal with a Provider via extracting store (as you have done) as of now.

Comment: thanks for replying. I didnt change the code and nothing crashed! so i guess it looks ugly but it works.